# Why this simple "drag to resize block" JavaScript doesn't work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

This page works well even in IE6, but in Chrome it's not working.  I thought it might because that Chrome ignored my function to perform the default "drag and open".

Is here any one can tell me how to modify this function to fit Chrome?

It seems stackoverflow not supporting pasting whole HTML page, so I pasted it here:

http://www.blogjava.net/jayslong/articles/351922.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setCapture/releaseCapture is not supported by chrome.

Comment: So is there any replacement ?

Comment: addEventListener and removeEventListener should be a proper way in all browsers except IE<9

Comment: Finally I implemented the YUI from yahoo to make the drag and resizable block.